# Annual-based proportion of values in two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have data for many months, there are many points for each month, I need to calculate how many times 0 from column1 appears with 1 from column2 in the specific year, devided by how many times 0 appears in column1 in the year.
Simple example:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame({'month':pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01', end='2019-01-01')}) 
temp['col1'] = np.random.randint(3, size=len(temp))
temp['col2'] = np.random.randint(3, size=len(temp))
```

The maximum I get is how many times different pairs of values from column1 and column2 appear together in different years:

```
temp2 = temp.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='month', freq='A')).apply(lambda x: x.groupby('col1')['col2'].value_counts())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want to do this:

```
temp['year'] = temp.month.apply(lambda x : x.year)
temp['condition'] = temp.apply(lambda row : ((row['col1'] == 0) and (row['col2'] == 1))*1,    
                               axis=1)
output = temp.groupby('year').apply(lambda df :   \
                          (df.condition.sum())/(df.col1.apply(lambda x: (x==0)*1).sum()))
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, but one also need to add 'x' in the first row, also closing parenthesis in the end